# The form tag just appears on first element of a foreach

Tags: php, cakephp, foreach, cakephp-2.0

I don't know why the form `teste` only appear on the first result of  the `foreach`.

Note:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
            'url' => array('controller' => 'menus', 'action' => 'reprovar', $procuracao['Attorney']['id'])
             )); ?>`
```

This appears in every result of the `foreach`.

The tag `<FORM>` of the `<?php echo $this->Form->create('teste'); ?>` only appears in the first result.

In every element, the textarea and the button appears.

The full code:

```
<?php foreach ($procuracoes as $procuracao): ?>
                <td><?php echo $procuracao['Attorney']['nome']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $procuracao['Attorney']['estadocivil']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $procuracao['Attorney']['identidade'].'/'.$procuracao['Attorney']['expedidor']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $procuracao['Attorney']['cpf']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $procuracao['Attorney']['status']; ?></td>
                <td><ul>
                <?php foreach ($procuracao['Power'] as $power): ?>
            <li>    <?php echo $power['resumo'] ?> </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul></td>

                <td>
                    <?php if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id') == $procuracao['Attorney']['aprovador'] AND $procuracao['Attorney']['fluxo'] == 0 OR $this->Session->read('Auth.User.nivel') == 'administrador') : ?>
                    <div id="botoes-small">

                <ul>
                <input type="button" value="Aprovar" class="btn btn-success aprovar">
                <div class="formaprovar">

                <?php echo $this->Form->create('teste'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('testerrr', array('placeholder' => 'teste')); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Ok', array('class' =>'btn btn-success', 'div' => false)); ?>

                </div>




                <input type="button" value="Reprovar" class="btn btn-danger reprovar">
                <div class="formreprovar">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
                'url' => array('controller' => 'menus', 'action' => 'reprovar', $procuracao['Attorney']['id'])
                )); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('motivo', array('placeholder' => 'Motivo')); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Ok', array('class' =>'btn btn-success pull-left', 'div' => false)); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
                    </div>

                    <?php if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id') == $procuracao['Attorney']['aprovador'] AND $procuracao['Attorney']['fluxo'] == 1): ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            <b>Aprovado</b>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id') == $procuracao['Attorney']['aprovador'] AND $procuracao['Attorney']['fluxo'] == 3): ?>
                        <div class="alert alert-error">
                            <b>Recusado</b>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I've edited out some of the obnoxious attributes of your post. Please do not write in all CAPS.

Comment: URGENT!! MY COMPANY NEEDS THIS BY 5PM YOU NEED TO FIX THIS FOR ME NOW. - I cleaned it up a little as well.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ I don't understand your comment. I don't have company.

Comment: Why are you opening tons of forms without ever closing them again? And no, submit() doesnt close a form - see the documentation.

Comment: @mark But the second form works and it is closed with submit.

Comment: Please read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#closing-the-form

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, if looks like that form element is emitted inside an IF statement.  Can you try taking it out?  I am not sure exactly when you would or would not need to output the form tag, but that might be what is preventing it.

EDIT--it looks like you are naming the form "teste", the second form is not named.  Trying taking the form name out--maybe it doesn't like them being named the same thing.

Comment: Thanks...But the second form works and its inside of the same "if"